# Extract texts of QHeaderView

Tags: qt4, qstandarditemmodel

I use `QStandardModel::setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "XXX")` to set the header text, how could I extract it from the model?

I've checked the document about both `QHeaderView` and `QStandardItemModel`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get QStandardItem representing headerItem using horizontalHeaderItem() API of QStandardItemModel.

```
QStandardItem * QStandardItemModel::horizontalHeaderItem(int column) const
```

then you can use text() API from QStandartItem to retrieve text back.

```
QString QStandardItem::text () const
```